# Custom link in htaccess without changing <a href="">?

Tags: html, .htaccess, url, hyperlink, href

I got this: `<a href="contact.php">`

This is just an example but let's try to solve on this.

I got a RewriteRule for this, this is my whole htaccess code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^kontakt contact.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I'd like to don't change my html code in 30 files so here is my question :

Is any way to DON'T CHANGE html code and make this?

Clicking at `<a href="contact.php">` makes url to `www.example.com/kontakt`

Comment: You can use 301 redirects. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/301-redirects/

Comment: I used : Redirect 301 /contact.php /kontakt

Comment: But the thing is that after this it makes redirect loop :/

Comment: Will you please share your entire htaccess code?

Comment: Yes, that's all

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^kontakt contact.php [NC]

Redirect 301 /contact.php /kontakt


RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/XM4JINe

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^kontakt contact.php  [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: It didn't solve this. I can go to /kontakt, It work's but still when I click a href it goes to : contact.php :/

Comment: This R=301 makes that /kontakt doesn't work for some reason